# Intelligent Merge of two Arrays (3-way-kindof)

Tags: javascript, merge

I have two Arrays, each represents a list of Stories. Two users can concurrently modify the order, add or remove Stories, and I want those changes merged.

An example should make this clearer

```
Original       1,2,3,4,5
UserA (mine)   3,1,2,4,5 (moved story 3 to start)
UserB (theirs) 1,2,3,5,4 (moved story 5 forward)
```

The result of the above should be

```
Merge (result) 3,1,2,5,4
```

In case of conflicts, UserA should always win.

I came pretty far with this simple approach. First i deleted whatever mine says i should deleted (that part of the code is not shown, it's trivial), then I iterate over mine, inserting and moving from theirs what is needed (mstories = mine, tstories = theirs):

```
     for (var idx=0;idx<mstories.length;idx++) {
        var storyId = mstories[idx];

        // new story by theirs
        if (tstories[idx] !== undefined && mstories.indexOf(tstories[idx]) == -1) {
           mstories.splice(idx+1, 0, tstories[idx]);
           idx--;
           continue;
        }
        // new story by mine
        if (tstories.indexOf(storyId) == -1 && ostories.indexOf(storyId) == -1) {
           tstories.splice(idx+offset, 0, storyId);
           offset += 1;
        // story moved by me
        } else if ((tstories.indexOf(storyId) != idx + offset) && ostories.indexOf(storyId) != idx) {
           tstories.splice(tstories.indexOf(storyId), 1);
           tstories.splice(idx+offset, 0, storyId);
        // story moved by them
        } else if (tstories.indexOf(storyId) != idx + offset) {
           mstories.splice(mstories.indexOf(storyId), 1);
           mstories.splice(idx+offset, 0, storyId);
           mdebug(storyId, 'S moved by them, moffset--');
        }
     }
     result = tstories
```

It's close, but it gets confused when too many Stories are moved to the front / back with Stories in between, which the other User touched.

I have an extended version which does checks on the original and is smarter - holding 2 offsets, etc - , but I feel like this is a problem that must have a) a name b) a perfect solution and i don't want to re-invent it.

Comment: Checkout Operational Transformation that is commonly used for for concurrency control in collaborative systems. Google Wave heavily uses it for keeping documents synchronized. http://www.waveprotocol.org/whitepapers/operational-transform, Wikipedia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation

Comment: Interesting problem! I would very much like to see the solution for it. I tried at it for a bit with no luck, maybe I'll try again when I don't have a headache.

Comment: indeed OT helped me. the solution was to extract the set of operations (move, insert, delete) for both changes, then transform one of the changes (basically the offsets) to be applicable after the other .. then apply both.

i now doubt that this can be written understandably in one loop as i tried.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a function that iterates over the supplied arrays and lets another function decide how to merge at a given index.  (see [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_Pattern))

```
// params:
//   original, a, b: equally dimensioned arrays
//   mergeStrategy : function with params _original, _a, _b that
//                   accept the values inhabiting the arrays
//                   original, a, and b resp.
//       
//                  - Is called for each array index.  
//                  - Should return one of the arguments passed.
//                  - May throw "conflict" exception.
// returns merged array

function merge(original, a, b, mergeStrategy){
    var result=[];

    for ( var i =0; i< a.length; i++ )  {
        try {
            result.push( mergeStrategy( original[i], a[i], b[i] ));
        } catch (e if e=="conflict") {
            throw ("conflict at index "+i);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here are some usage examples ... yours:

```
// example:  always choose a over b
function aWins( original, a, b ) {
    return ( original == a ) ? b : a;
}

// returns [3,1,2,5,4]    
merge(
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [3,1,2,4,5],
    [1,2,3,5,4], aWins);
```

... and one that throws an exception upon conflict:

```
function complain( original, a, b ) {
    if (original == a )
        return b;

    if (original == b )
        return a;

    if ( a == b )
        return a;

    throw ("conflict");
}

// throws "conflict at index 3"    
merge(
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [3,1,2,1,5],
    [1,2,3,5,4], complain);
```